# SciPy curve_fit with np.log returns immediately with popt = p0, pcov = inf

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, logarithm

I'm trying to optimize a logarithmic fit to a data set with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. Before trying it on an actual data set, I wrote code to run on a dummy data set.

```
def do_fitting():
    x = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
    y = func(x, 1.1, .4, 5)
    y2 = y + 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=len(x))

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y2, p0=np.array([2, 0.5, 1]))

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label="Clean Data")
    plt.plot(x, y2, 'ko', label="Fuzzed Data")
    plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Of course, `do_fitting()` relies on `func()`, which it passes to `curve_fit`. Here's the problem. When I pass a `func()` that contains `np.log`, i.e. the function that I actually want to fit to, `curve_fit` declares that `p0` (the initial condition) is the optimal solution and returns immediately with an infinite covariance.

Here's what happens if I run `do_fitting()` with a non-logarithmic `func()`:

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(x*b) + c
```

[image: exponential fit]

```
popt = [ 0.90894173  0.44279212  5.19928151]
pcov = [[ 0.02044817 -0.00471525 -0.02601574]
        [-0.00471525  0.00109879  0.00592502]
        [-0.02601574  0.00592502  0.0339901 ]]
```

Here's what happens when I run `do_fitting()` with a logarithmic `func()`:

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.log(x*b) + c
```

[image: logarithmic fit]

```
popt = [ 2.   0.5  1. ]
pcov = inf
```

You'll notice that the logarithmic solution for `popt` is equal to the value I gave `curve_fit` for `p0` in the above `do_fitting()`. This is true, and `pcov` is infinite, for every value of `p0` I have tried.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: One possibility is that you're taking the log of 0 or a negative number. It's impossible to tell, since you haven't shown us what `func` actually *is*  - all we know is that it contains `np.log` somewhere.

Comment: @ali_m added func in edit. Thought I'd had it in there all along; sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is very simple - since the first value in your `x` array is 0, you are taking the log of 0, which is equal to `-inf`:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
p0 = np.array([2, 0.5, 1])

print(func(x, *p0).min())
# -inf
```

Comment: Yup, caught it as soon as you posted your comment. Sorry I didn't include the function the first time around; could've sworn I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fit a logarithmic function just fine using the following code (hardly modified from your original):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.log(x+b) + c

def do_fitting():
    x = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
    y = func(x, 1.1, .4, 5)
    y2 = y + 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=len(x))

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y2, p0=np.array([2, 0.5, 1]))

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label="Clean Data")
    plt.plot(x, y2, 'ko', label="Fuzzed Data")
    plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

do_fitting()
```

(Unfortunately I can't post a picture of the final fit, but it agrees quite nicely with the clean data).

Likely your problem is not the logarithm itself, but some difficulty curve_fit is having with the specific function you're trying to fit. Can you edit your question to provide an example of the exact logarithmic function you're trying to fit?

EDIT: The function you provided is not well-defined for x=0, and produces a RuntimeWarning upon execution. curve_fit is not good at handling NaNs, and will not be able to fit the function in this case. If you change x to

```
x = np.linspace(1, 4, 100)
```

curve_fit performs just fine.

Comment: Already done, per ali_m's suggestion. The function was taking the log of 0 (the first term in the linspace), which is why your `np.log(x+b)` func() worked - b made it nonzero. D'oh.

Comment: Edited. Looks like y'all were able to figure it out while I was typing up this answer, though.